# Copying names from individual cells from excel and creating/saving a new word document for each name using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Given an unspecified list a names in column A of an excel spreadsheet, I would like to create multiple word docs for each individual name in the list. I also want the each name to become the name of the word doc followed by today's date i.e. Michael_03232017.docx

I have looked up examples of similar problems but they are all a bit too complicating as I am still a beginner. I'm having trouble getting started other than setting the range of cells that need to be iterated through.

Here is what I have started with:

```
Sub WordDocTransf()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wdAPP As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object

    set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A".End(xlup).Row)

End Sub
```

I don't know how to implement wdAPP and wdDoc objects.
Need some help getting started please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested that this will create the files as specified. I leave to you to research how to actually populate the Word documents.

```
Sub WordDocTransf()
    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    For Each cell In Rng
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

        dateStr = "_" & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00") & CStr(Year(Date))

        With wrdDoc
            If Dir("C:\your_folder\" & cell.Value & dateStr & ".doc") <> "" Then
                Kill "C:\your_folder\" & cell.Value & dateStr & ".doc"
            End If
            .SaveAs ("C:\your_folder\" & cell.Value & dateStr & ".doc")
            .Close
        End With
    Next
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```